# Check if given number is Even, Odd or Neither in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point, numbers, integer

How can I get if a number is even or odd or neither (have decimal, like `1.5`) with PHP? I know that there are operators like `*`, `/`, but they did not work.
Here's a try (of course it did not) (work that's just to find if it's a even number):

```
function even($n) {
    return (($n/2)*2 == $n);
}
echo even(1); // true (should be false)
echo even(2); // true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple. modulo (%) is the operator you want, it determines if there would be a remainder if x is divided by y... for example (3 % 2 = 1) and (4 % 2 = 0).
This has been asked before too - pretty common question - you really just need to see if your number, $n % 2 is equal to 0.

[php test if number is odd or even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959247/php-test-if-number-is-odd-or-even)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
function even($n) {
    if (!is_int($n)) {return 'n';}
    return !($n % 2);
}

even(1); // false;
even(2); // true;
even(1.5); // 'n'
```

The danger here is that 'n' will evaluate as `false` if used as a boolean. It might be better to return some specific constants instead of true or false. The OP didn't specify what the return values should be.

Comment: Am I missing something - I can't work out why this `return 'n'` is there vs `false`? Is that to represent "neither"?

Comment: If the argument is not an integer return 'n' for 'neither' - OP wasn't very clear on this point.

Comment: Hmm.. Perhaps some constants to use for the return value would be cleaner (e.g. `EVEN`, `ODD`, `NEITHER`) vs mixing return types.

Comment: Cool. I'd love to remove that downvote but unfortunately it is not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Check if given number is `integer` first. And bitwise `&` to check if it is even or odd. Here is an example...

```
if (is_int($n)) {
    if ($n & 1) {
        echo 'Odd!';
    } else {
        echo 'Even!';
    }
} else {
    echo "Not a Integer!";
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo operator (`%`) to determine whether the integer is divisible by 2. You also need `abs()` to handle negative numbers, and `is_int()` to handle the fact that the modulo operator doesn't correctly handle floating point numbers. An example implementation follows:

```
function is_even($num) {
    return is_int($num) && abs($num % 2) == 0;
}
function is_odd($num) {
    return is_int($num) && abs($num % 2) == 1;
}
// this last one seems self-explanatory, but if you want it, here it is
function is_neither_even_nor_odd($num) {
    return !is_even($num) && !is_odd($num);
}

// Tests: The following should all output true:
var_dump(
    is_even(0),
    is_even(2),
    is_even(-6),
    is_even(51238238),
    is_odd(1),
    is_odd(-1),
    is_odd(57),
    is_neither_even_nor_odd(1.5),
    is_neither_even_nor_odd(2.5),
    is_neither_even_nor_odd(-0.5),
    is_neither_even_nor_odd(0.00000001)
    );
```

[Here's a demo](http://ideone.com/ial4DM).

Comment: The modulo operator cannot be trusted with non-integers: `2.5 % 2 == 0 // => true`

Answer (score 0):

[`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) returns true if the given variable is a number

[`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) returns true if the given variable is an integer

The modulor operator `%` can be used to determine if an integer is even or odd:

```
$num % 2 == 0 // returns true if even, false if odd
```

Comment: Returning the favor, since you pointed it out on my answer: `$num % 2 == 0` also returns true for non-integers like 2.5...