# how can i pick out odd numbers from a series of numbers

Tags: php, random, numbers, series

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<=13)
{
   $rev=rand(0,9);
   $Rev=strrev($rev);
   echo $Rev;
   $i++;
}
?>
```

The above code generates a series of numbers which are reversed ...the idea is to calculate the luhn digit which requires that you pick out odd numbers ...please how can I achieve this ??

Comment: What is your current output and what do you expect to get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php test if number is odd or even](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959247/php-test-if-number-is-odd-or-even)

Comment: Improved code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i=1;

while($i<=13){

    $rev=rand(0,9);
    $rev=strrev($rev);

    if ($rev % 2 != 0) {
        echo $rev;
    }

$i++;


}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$i = 0;
while($i<=13){

    $rev=rand(0,9);
    $rev=strrev($rev);

    $all_numbers[] = $rev;

    if ($rev % 2 != 0) {
        $odd_numbers[] = $rev;
    }

$i++;


}

echo "<h2>All numbers</h2><pre>";
print_r($all_numbers);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<h2>Odd numbers</h2><pre>";
print_r($odd_numbers);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the code you wrote no longer generates the usual 14 digits..please I mean after it generates the 14 digits the next thing is to pick out the odds from it...not directly generate odds