# How can I make this PHP lines shorter?

Tags: php, loops, count, alternate

I have this loop at the same it will count the output:

```
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); $current++; $current2++;
```

Then to call the proper html class I need this for my design:

```
<div class="span4 <?php if($current == 0) { echo 'first'; } elseif($current == 1) { echo 'second'; } elseif($current == 2) { echo 'first'; } elseif($current == 3) { echo 'second'; } ?>" id="<? echo $current; ?>">
```

The `$count` starts from 0 and `$count2` from 1. The output should be like this: if 0=first, 1=second, 2=first, 3=second and so forth. How can I make this expression shorter with unlimited number of `$count`? I hope my question is clear. Thank you for those who will help me here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking here, I think you want to alternate your divs with'first' and 'second' classes?

As such, you can use the % modulo operator (see http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)

```
<div class="span4 <?php echo ($current % 2 === 0 ? 'first' : 'second'); ?>" id="<? echo $current; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using these class names for alternating CSS styles there is a much elegant way to do this using CSS3

Your HTML

```
<div class="span4" id="<? echo $current; ?>">
```

And in your css file

```
.span4:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
.span4:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

else for a PHP solution the answer by Liam Wiltshire should work good.

source: [CSS even and odd rules examples](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<div class="span4 
 <?php if ($curent%2 == 0){ echo 'first'; } 
  else {echo 'second';}?> id="<? echo $current; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

So you could use `mod` - best to use the full`<?php` tag for WordPress if that is what it is.

[php test if number is odd or even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959247/php-test-if-number-is-odd-or-even)

```
    // set up the html clips
    if($current % 2 == 0){
    $html_clips = 'first'; 
    }else{
    $html_clips = 'second'; 
    }
    if($current == 0) $html_clips = 'first';
    <div class="span4 <?php echo $html_clips ?>" id="<?php echo $current; ?>">
```

Comment: Hi Steve, this works as long as you know the number of elements - as per the OP's question, it should work on any number if items.

Comment: So you could use if($current % 2 == 0){  $html_clips = 'first';

Comment: Sorry somehow I missed your earlier answer - good one! Upvoted.