# question below check if even odd without %2 == 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i have X=10 and i wanna check if its even then 'win' compare with value scale 0-9 like if x = 1,3,5,7,9 = win otherwise 'lose', but don't wanna use % 2 == 0

```
if(X=1,3,5,7,9){
    echo "win";
 }
```

thanks

Comment: Alternatives for checking if a number is odd can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959247/test-if-number-is-odd-or-even/9153969#9153969

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if number is odd or even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959247/test-if-number-is-odd-or-even)

Comment: why you don't wanna use % 2 == 0 ?

Comment: you said even means win but code says odd means win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using **in_array**

```
if (in_array($x, [1,3,5,7,9]) {
    echo "win";
}
```

Comment: do you understand what OP wants here `compare with value scale 0-9` I dont understand.

Comment: yeah, since it has a defined set of values to compare we can use in_array, as they don't want to use %

Comment: can you add value for $x, or runnable to any live demo ?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

here is the right way
$x%2 for even = 0, for odd = 1, when ever odd value come it will echo win, with in array you have to define odd values in array.

```
if ($x%2) {
  echo "win";
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to use `modulus` though.

Comment: thanks for your answer bro i got the solution above :D

Answer (score 1):

CREDIT TO https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-check-number-even-odd/

Try this `Bitwise AND` method   **`and its is NOT USING %2 == 0`**

```
function checkIsEvenOrOdd($number) 
{ 

    // One 
    $one = 1; 

    // Bitwise AND 
    $bitwiseAnd = $number & $one; 

    if($bitwiseAnd != 1) 
    { 
        echo "Even";  
    } 
    else{ 
        echo "Odd"; 
    } 
} 
echo checkIsEvenOrOdd('2');
echo checkIsEvenOrOdd('1');
echo checkIsEvenOrOdd('97');
```

HOPE ITS HELPS